# GeForce GT 750M graphics driver for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus

My computer has an NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M graphics card. It's unknown in Ubuntu 12.04. My graphics card is unknown in System Details. In Additional Drivers, no proprietary driver is found.

I tried to install nvidia-current, but it doesn't work. I couldn't even login to Ubuntu after I installed nvidia-current.

Comment: How did you install the driver?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  To install Nvidia Drivers, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

If that doesn't work, you can download the [32bit](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/61452) or [64bit](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/61453) drivers from Nvidia.

Comment: I have tried to install nvidia-current, but it didn't work and made   me can't log in ubuntu......

Answer (score 0):

NVIDIA driver for GeForce GT 750M is available at (depending on your platform - 32 or 64-bit):

http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-319.17-driver.html

http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-319.17-driver.html

Installation instruction is as follows:

1. boot into console as root [( how to )](http://www.cebuntu.com/how-to/how-to-boot-your-ubuntu-desktop-in-terminal-mode/)
2. service lightdm stop
3. cd into the directory containing NVIDIA*.run file
4. `sh ./NVIDIA*.run reboot`

Good luck and have fun.